# How can I force the position of a figure while using the MNRAS template?

Tags: floats, journal-publishing

I'm trying to force the position of a figure in a document I'm writing, however, it's an MNRAS template and is two columned. I've tried using `[H]` and `[h!]` for the figure, however, they don't work. Is there another way to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: you have given no indication of the code you have used so hard to tell you what is wrong. `\includegraphics` is never moved, and if you do not want it to move you should not wrap it in `figure` but if you do use `figure` and `[H]` from the float package it will not move.  But the only reason to use `figure` is to allow it to be moved.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380712/floating-tables/380726#380726

Answer (score 2):

From the MNRAS LaTeX guide for authors: "The LATEX float placement commands [htbp] are intentionally disabled. Layout of figures and tables will be adjusted by the publisher during the production process, so authors should not concern themselves with placement to avoid disappointment and wasted effort. Simply place the LATEX code close to where the figure or table is first mentioned in the text and leave exact placement to the publishers." ([source](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/mnras_guide.pdf))